# How can I write Bison rule with 0 or 1+ tokens without S/R conflicts?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

If I defined tokens like normal *object access* :

```cpp
[$_a-zA-Z]+[.] { return ACCESS; }
[$_a-zA-Z]+    { return ID; }
[+]            { return PLUIS;  }
```

And the Bison grammar rules:

```cpp
Accesses
    : Accesses ACCESS    { /*do something...*/ }
    | ACCESS             { /*do something...*/ }

Expression    
    : Accesses ID PLUS Accesses ID    { /*do something...*/ }
```

I want to allow such contents in source codes:

```cpp
moduleA.valueB.valueC + valueD
```

In the example, if I don't put empty rule in `Accesses`, the single `ID` variable like `valueD` is illegal. But if I put the empty rule in, `Accesses` will cause seriously S/R conflicts, and texts it matched will become strange.

And, I don't think duplicate the rules in `Expression` is a good idea, ex:

```cpp
Expression    
    : Accesses ID PLUS Accesses ID   { /*do something...*/ }
    | ID PLUS Accesses ID            { /*do something...*/ }
    | Accesses ID PLUS ID            { /*do something...*/ }
    | ID PLUS ID                     { /*do something...*/ }
```

Can I find other ways to solve this problem ?

**EDIT**: Ok thanks to your answer noticed me this simple grammar got no conflicts. At least you let me know that the real problem may hide in somewhere else ( what a mess for a compiler newbie ! ).

Comment: There are no shift reduce conflicts from the Expression rule you have if you change the Accesses rule to allow epsilon, so the problem you have must be elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:
lex:

```
[$_a-zA-Z]+ {return WORD;}
"."         {return DOT;}
"+"         {return PLUS;}
```

bison:

```
Expression   : Value PLUS Value;
Value        : WORD|WORD AccessList;
AccessElement: DOT WORD;
AccessList   : AccessElement|AccessList AccessElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with just using an epsilon production in your example:

```
Expression    
    : Accesses ID PLUS Accesses ID    { /*do something...*/ }
;

Accesses
    : Accesses ACCESS    { /*do something...*/ }
    |                    { /*do something...*/ }
;
```

gives no conflicts....